# Clone row of elements in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this Angular form http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=ph0QHW513czywawl.
I need to clone the row on clicking ADD (+) and delete selected row on clicking DELETE (-).
Looking for a solution in AngularJS only. In current solution, the scopes are not working correctly. Also did not yet figure out how to implement (-) functionality.

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="padding: 10px;">
<br/>
<div style="width: 90%; display: inline-block; border: 1px silver solid;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="hr.langauge.level" tooltip="Level">
        <option value="Native" ng-selected="true">Native</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="hr.langauge.name" tooltip="Language">
        <option value="">Language</option>
        <option value="EN">English</option>
        <option value="IT">Italian</option>
        <option value="DE">German</option>
        <option value="FR">French</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="hr.langauge.remark" class="form-control" placeholder="Remark" tooltip="Remark">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div select-last ng-repeat='item in items'></div>
</div>
<a class="btn" style="margin-bottom: 27px;" href="#" tooltip="Add" ng-click='addRow()'>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</a>
```

```
{{hr.langauge | json}}
```

language.html

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="hr.langauge.level" tooltip="Level">
            <option value="">Level</option>
            <option value="proficient">Proficient</option>
            <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
            <option value="beginner">Beginner</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="hr.langauge.name" tooltip="Language">
            <option value="">Language</option>
            <option value="EN">English</option>
            <option value="IT">Italian</option>
            <option value="DE">German</option>
            <option value="FR">French</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="hr.langauge.remark" class="form-control" placeholder="Remark" tooltip="Remarks">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a class="btn" href="#" tooltip="Delete" ng-click="deleteRow({{$index}});">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
        </a>{{$index}}
    </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('selectLast', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'language.html'
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.newitem = '';

    $scope.addRow = function(){
        $scope.items.push($scope.newitem);
        console.log('+ clicked');
    }

    $scope.deleteRow = function(rowNo) {
        /*$scope.items.splice($scope.newitem);*/
        console.log('- clicked in row ' + rowNo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the controller code?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a custom directive at all here. You can achieve this with a simple ng-repeat. Have you tried implementing this yourself? I don't see any javascript.

Comment: @lucuma I tried to put some code but after it did not really work, I decided to leave it empty.

Comment: @CharlieMartin I tried it more after posting. Here it is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=ph0QHW513czywawl). (-) is not working and scopes are broken.

Comment: @khdilshod, I've posted an answer to your question about removing a row. It looks like you've solved the add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment and plunker, it looks like you have the `Add` figured out.  The remove row is easier.  All you need to do is splice out the row.  The issue on your view is you have the index surrounded by {{}} which isn't necessary.

```
$scope.deleteRow = function(rowNo) {
    /*$scope.items.splice($scope.newitem);*/
    $scope.languages.splice(rowNo, 1);
    console.log('- clicked in row ' + rowNo);
};

  <a class="btn" href="#" tooltip="Delete" ng-click="deleteRow($index);">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
    </a>{{$index}}
```

Here is an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7vW24aDyZH02LO1iO7F3?p=preview&s=ph0QHW513czywawl

Comment: Thanks. It is nice! Now I'm stuck with scopes that I have. If you noticed, I am rendering my scope on the page. Cannot figure out it again, reading angular wiki on github. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

functionality is to have a click edit a row entry, create a temporary copy of the row data, then update.
Below link

https://thinkster.io/egghead/angular-copy/